# Nautilus Bookmarks stick to mouse

Tags: nautilus, mouse

When I single click on a bookmark in Nautilus 3.26.4, it adheres to the pointer and gets dragged along. How can I fix this? This has happened to me on Ubuntu 16, 17, and 18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out the following commands to resolve this issue:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences  click-policy
```

If you get something as an output, go ahead with this command:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.nautilus.preferences  click-policy
```

If the above command still lists single and double as options, then proceed with the below command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences  click-policy single
```

If all goes well, your issue will no longer be in existence. Let us know in the comments below.

Comment: I encountered the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04. After some Googling, Your answer solved the problem perfectly! But it's a shame that such an obvious bug isn't acknowledged on Launchpad and isn't being fixed. See
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1787930

Comment: By the way, after running the last command in your answer, Nautilus switched to "single-click" mode and a folder can be opened by just a single click. I typed the command
"gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences  click-policy double"
to restore the "double-click" mode which was the default. I'm pleasantly surprised that the bookmark dragging issue didn't return, so in the end everything works for me.

Comment: Update: the problem comes back from time to time. The only sure way to solve the problem seems to be logging out and logging in again, which is rather annoying. Also, at least for me,  the problem affects not just Nautilus bookmarks, but also other applications like Zoom, making the mouse close to unusable sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching online, I found the following Launchpad bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rapidsvn/+bug/402892

Apparently it's an old GNOME bug which is still unfixed.